# Convert string of character and number into integer?

Tags: javascript

I want to convert this string "F1" into an integer 1.

For example

```
"F1" ===> 1
"F2" ===> 2
"F3" ===> 3
```

So far, this is what I've done

```
parseLevel: function(level) {
    var levels = {
        "F1": 1,
        "F2": 2
    };
    return levels[level];
}
```

Here's the function

```
parseLevel: function (level) {
  return parseInt(level, 10);
}
```

I'm getting an error says it's NaN

Comment: Does your string always start with an "F"? And will it always have a number after the first "F"?

Comment: @NalinRanjan yes

Comment: what result should it produce if the input is invalid? `NaN` or `0`?

Comment: @NalinRanjan it says NaN

Comment: There is an answer below, does it work for you ?

Comment: @NalinRanjan yeah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the string you pass has a leading `F` in it; `parseInt` can't figure out what integer `F1` could be so just strip the `F` of the string.

```js
parseLevel: function (level) {
  return parseInt(level.slice(1), 10);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of how you could parse any string and only use its digits. to parse an integer.

```
let s = "ajs382bop";//can be any string it will strip all non digits
function stripAndReturnNumber(s){
    return parseInt(s.replace(/\D/g, ""));
    //This will replace all non digits with nothing and leave all digits remaining.
    //Then it will return the resulting integer.
}
console.log(stripAndReturnNumber(s));//382
```